# Error while using rangeConstraint for created field in StructuredQueryDefinition in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, java

I am trying to get documents for which creation date(created field) has value greater than `"2014-04-25T02:11:10-07:00"` using this:

```
qb.rangeConstraint("created", Operator.GT, "2014-04-25T02:11:10-07:00")
```

But I am getting

> **[Fatal Error] :9:102: Character reference "&#17" is an invalid XML character.**

I also tried this:

```
qb.rangeConstraint("created", Operator.GT, "2014-02-25")
```

Full stack trace for your reference:

```
[Fatal Error] :9:102: Character reference "&#17" is an invalid XML character.
Exception in thread "main"
com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: Could not construct search results: parser error
at com.marklogic.client.io.SearchHandle.receiveContent(SearchHandle.java:160)
at com.marklogic.client.io.SearchHandle.receiveContent(SearchHandle.java:75)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.search(QueryManagerImpl.java:177)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.search(QueryManagerImpl.java:140)
at com.marklogic.client.example.tutorial.SearchProperties.main(SearchProperties.java:52)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#17" is an invalid XML character.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.marklogic.client.io.SearchHandle.receiveContent(SearchHandle.java:157)
... 4 more
```

I have added element range index as well on last-modified field in my database.
So please let me know the probable causes for this error. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried few changes while firing rangeConstraint query and now my query call is like :
qb.properties(qb.rangeConstraint("modofied",Operator.GT, "2014-04-25"));
So now I am getting below specified error:
Exception in thread "main" com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: search failed: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) cts:properties-query(()) -- arg1 is not of type cts:query
Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: That `XDMP-ARGTYPE` error means what it says: you can't have an empty properties-query. Do you have a typo in your code? Should `modofied` be `modified` or perhaps `prop:last-modified`?

Comment: Yes that was a typo, but after changing it to "modified" and "last-modified", it is giving same error as earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is puzzling.  The error is thrown when parsing the search response because an illegal character is found.

If you get the response as a string using StringHandle and print that, the output might giving you some clues about what's wrong with the response.

You could also print out the structured query that you get from the query builder to see what the Java client is sending to the server.

Just to confirm:  have you created query options corresponding to the constraint?  If not, you should either create the query options first or just use a range query on the element directly as described in:

[http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#range%28com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.RangeIndex,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.Operator,%20java.lang.Object...%29](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#range%28com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.RangeIndex,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.Operator,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum

Comment: Yes I have created options corresponding to the constraint. I am pasting my code snippet along with the stack trace. 
**Code**: 
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder("tutorial");

StructuredQueryDefinition query =qb.properties(qb.rangeConstraint("modified-date",Operator.GT, "2014-04-25"));

SearchHandle resultsHandle = queryMgr.search(query, new SearchHandle());

Comment: **Stack trace:**
Exception in thread "main" com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: search failed: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) cts:properties-query(()) -- arg1 is not of type cts:query
 at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.search(JerseyServices.java:1214)
 at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.search(QueryManagerImpl.java:177)
 at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.search(QueryManagerImpl.java:140)
 at com.marklogic.client.example.tutorial.StructuredQuery.main(StructuredQuery.java:56)
Thanks.

Comment: I got XML and JSON format to specify Structured Query having RangeConstraint in search-dev guide, but something is going wrong while building this query using StructuredQueryDefinition.

So can someone please let me know exact function call to get the documents added/modified after certain timestamp/date. 
Thanks in advance.